# The del operation is not executed when the response object is returned in the Scrapy download middleware

Tags: python, scrapy

I am writing a download middleware that connects Scrapy to Selenium:

```py
# spider.py
import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    # allowed_domains = ['xxx.com']
    start_urls = ['http://httpbin.org/']

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response)

# Middleware.py 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse


class SeleniumMiddleware:
    """Docking Selenium"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.browser.maximize_window()
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10)

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls()

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        try:
            # Determine which links need to be accessed using the selenium program
            if request.url in spider.start_urls:
                self.browser.get(request.url)

                # wait data load
                self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
                    By.ID, 'operations-tag-HTTP_Methods')))

                page_text = self.browser.page_source  # get data

                # return Response
                print('1')
                return HtmlResponse(url=request.url, body=page_text, encoding='utf-8', request=request, status=200)
        except TimeoutException:
            # Timeout
            print('2')
            return HtmlResponse(url=request.url, status=500, request=request)

    def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
        print(f'Error: {exception}')
        return None

    def __del__(self):
        print('Browser close~')
        self.browser.quit()
```

When I tested the program, I found that when the response object was returned, the program did not perform the del operation, which caused the opened browser to fail to close as expected.

Output result:

```
1
<200 http://httpbin.org/>
```

It can be seen that no exception was triggered when the program was running, but the program did not use del to delete this middleware.

When I comment the code that returns the response object, the program will execute the del operation:

```py
# return Response
print('1')
# return HtmlResponse(url=request.url, body=page_text, encoding='utf-8', request=request, status=200)
```

Output result:

```
1
<200 http://httpbin.org/>
Browser close~
```

I want to know what caused this result, and how should I perform the finishing operation (close the browser) when the response object is returned?

Hope you can help me, thanks.

Already resolved，Please use the `spider_closed` method and connect to the signal when creating the middleware:

```py
--skip--
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    o = cls()
    crawler.signals.connect(o.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    return o

--skip--

def spider_closed(self):
    """Close the browser"""
    self.browser.quit()
```

Comment: I'm sorry, *when and why do you expect `__del__` to be called?*

Comment: You show us two classes, but I don't see that they're tied together in any way. How are you *using* those classes? How do you expect them to be interacting?

Comment: Such a middleware exists: [scrapy-selenium](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium). Have a look at that to see how you can quit the driver

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I hope that when the Scrapy program ends, this middleware can be released. From the description I gave, I can see that when `process_request` does not return a response object, the program can work as I expected. When the response object is returned, I The `__del__ ` method defined for this middleware was not executed.

Comment: Again, *why do you ever expect `__del__` to be called at all*?

Comment: @Blckknght Regarding the `TestSpider` class, it is obvious that it is a crawler class defined by a crawler file under the Scrapy project. Regarding the `SeleniumMiddleware` class, it is a middleware under the `Middlewares.py` file in the Scrapy project, and I indicated that they belong to which category above them. file

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga My brother, this middleware docked with selenium and opened a browser. I expect to execute `__del__` to release it when the program ends.

Comment: @tomjn Thank you for helping me ，It works great for me。